# How can we implement multiple core division with pyspark in local machine?

Tags: pyspark

My PC is an 18 core machine. I want to make use of all the cores at a time in order to avail the parallelism in pyspark.

```py
spark = (SparkSession
  .builder
  .master("local[18]")
  .appName("sparkexample")
  .getOrCreate())
```

I used the above query. Are all cores working together or I have to set any configuration file for the same?

Answer (score 0):

`local[*]` will use all the available cores.

```
  spark = (SparkSession
      .builder
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("sparkexample")
      .getOrCreate())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually i faced the issue when I run the program in a dual core and 18 core machine. Both machine took same execution time. I want to know why we couldnt get the advantage of  parallelism  with pyspark in this case

Comment: did you call an action (i.e show, collect)? otherwise, the spark is lazy, it just compiles the execution plan. Also, code has to be written in a way to reap the benefits of parallelization. If not done properly, the spark will actually perform worse because of the overhead cost of managing a cluster and data shuffling between the executors.. Maybe post the code.